# Merge two 4-bit numbers into an 8-bit number

Tags: assembly, x86-16

So the problem is:
There are 2 characters.
I need to build a 8-bit number that is built like this:
the left 4 bits from the first number, the right 4 bits from the second number

Edit:
if the number will be placed in al, the bits should be like this:

al bits 0 to 3 = lowest 4 bits of the second character.
al bits 4 to 7 = highest 4 bits of the first character.

I have tried to just shift right 4 bits the number to get the 4 left bits.
To get the right 4 bits I tried to turn the 4 left bits of the number to 0.
Then I added the 4 left bits to ax,shifted it left 4 times, and then added the left 4 bits.

```
    mov dl,[si]       ; the value of the character, it is inside of a char array
    shr dl,4
    add al,dl
    and dl,00001111b
    shl ax,4          ; ax value was 0
    inc si
    mov dl,[si]
    and dl,00001111b
    add al,dl
    shl ax,4
```

I thought this should work but apparently it doesn't.

How can I do it?

Comment: It's unclear why you `add al, dl` with `al` not being initialized. Also `and dl,00001111b` has no effect since you reload `dl`. Furthermore you are doing too many shifts for no reason and your output is 16 bits instead of 8. You basically just want `(a << 4) | (b & 15)`, e.g. `mov al, [si]; shl al, 4; mov dl, [si+1]; and dl, 15; or al, dl`.

Comment: @Jester you should post that as answer

Comment: Can you clarify the task: when you say left 4 bits from the first number, does that mean that the left 4 bits of the first character (so `0011`, if we're dealing with ASCII) go into the left 4 bits of the result? Or that *the first number* goes into the left 4 bits of the result?

Comment: @harold Here is an example: The ascii of the letter e is 101 which is 0110,0101 so lets say it appears 2 times. The result should be 0101,0110

Comment: @Jester Thank you for the answer. I do actually need to get a 16 bit number at the original problem.Posted it as 8 bit because I need to do the same proccess 2 times.Accidently showed the original code. So,to get a 16 bit number I just need to shift ax left 8 times and then do it again right?

Comment: @Jester I think you missunderstood the problem but I think I fixed it.By doing 'and dl,15' you get the right 4 bits of the number but you need to get the left 4 bits so I did: 'and dl,240' and then 'shl dl,4','or al,dl'   edit: I still dont know how to use StackOverflow properly,how do I write code examples in a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to build a 8-bit number that is built like this:
>   the left 4 bits from the first number, the right 4 bits from the second number

I don't know if you want something like this:

```
    mov ax,[si]     ;al = first character, ah = second character
    shl al,4        ;al bits 4 to 7 = lowest 4 bits of first character
    shr ax,4        ;al bits 0 to 3 = lowest 4 bits of first character, al bits 4 to 7 = lowest 4 bits of second character
```

..or something like this:

```
    mov ax,[si]     ;al = first character, ah = second character
    and ax,0xF00F   ;al bits 0 to 3 = lowest 4 bits of first character, ah bits 4 to 7 = highest 4 bits of second character
    or al,ah        ;al bits 0 to 3 = lowest 4 bits of first character, al bits 4 to 7 = highest 4 bits of second character
```

..or something like this:

```
    mov ax,[si]     ;al = first character, ah = second character
    and ax,0x0FF0   ;al bits 4 to 7 = highest 4 bits of first character, ah bits 0 to 3 = lowest 4 bits of second character
    or al,ah        ;al bits 0 to 3 = lowest 4 bits of second character, al bits 4 to 7 = highest 4 bits of first character
```

..or something else.

Comment: Here is an example: The ascii of the letter e is 101 which is  0110,0101 so lets say it appears 2 times. The result should be 0101,0110.

Comment: @TheNiv: So, highest 4 bits of result come from highest 4 bits of first character, and lowest 4 bits of result come from lowest 4 bits of second character?  Will add third  example for that case.

Comment: Yes,I understood how to do it though and it works now.